# How do I define bean of an Interface

Tags: java, spring-boot, interface, javabeans, spring-cloud-feign

I am using Feign client to connect to external endpoint
I have declared the endpoint in application.properties

```
@FeignClient(url = "${api.url}") 

public interface wealth {

@GetMapping("/items")

public Client getItems(@RequestParam("name") String name);

}
```

while I try to access the interface's endpoint from other class like

```
@service
public class WealthClient{
 
 public Wealth wealth;

 WealthClient(Wealth wealth){
this.wealth=wealth;

public Client getItems(String name){
return wealth.getItems(name);
}
```

Main class is

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients(clients = "{Wealth.class})
public class ExampleApplication {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I am getting Error like

consider defining bean of type Wealth in your configuration .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to add a concrete definition of Wealth and let Spring manage it.

Comment: @PrashantPandey can you please help me elaborate it .couldnt get it